# Starring messages in the chat transcript

Tags: support, chat, chat-stars, chat-transcript

It would be nice to have this ability.  I primarily encounter this issue when checking a transcript when I'm notified of a mention in the inbox.  I see awesome stuff and can't star it.  Makes me sad that I cannot share my appreciation.  Sideways frowny face.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You already can.

> [image]

Comment: I can herp this derp in five minutes.

Comment: Those be some insane freehand circles. Did you use the MSPaint graffiti tool?